# How to set a value to an input text element of a stateless function inside a Jest test

Tags: javascript, reactjs, enzyme, jestjs

Since Im using a stateless function I cannot use this:

`wrapper.find('input').instance().value = 'some text'`

this also is depreacted:

`wrapper.find('input').node.value = 'some text'`

Do you know what would be a proper way of achiving this ?
I'm little new to tests, so correct me if I'm wrong:

1. I created the component with `const component = mount(<PostMessages/>)`.
2. I targeted the text input like this: `const input = component.find('input')`.
3. **this is my missing peace**.

my Component:

```
const PostMessage = props => {
    let inputText;

    const onKeypressHandler = (e) => {
        if (e.key === 'Enter') {
            if (inputText.value) {
                sendMessage(inputText.value);
                clearInput();
            }
        }
    }

    const clearInput = () => {
        inputText.value = '';
    }

    const setRef = (input) => {
        if (input) {
            inputText = input;
            inputText.focus();
        }
    }

    const stringIsBlank = (str) => {
        return (!str || /^\s*$/.test(str));
    }

    const formatMessage = (message) => {
        return stringIsBlank(message) ? false : message.trim();
    }

    const sendMessage = (message) => {
        const formatedMessage = formatMessage(message);

        if(formatedMessage) {
            props.send(formatedMessage);
        }
    }

    return (
        <PostMessageStyle>
            <input type="text"
                placeholder="Your message..."
                onKeyPress={onKeypressHandler}
                ref={input => setRef(input)}
            />
            <button onClick={sendMessage}>Send</button>
        </PostMessageStyle>
    )
};
```

Comment: Perhaps pass the value down as ```prop``` from parent component?

Comment: @Varinder What do you mean pass the value as `prop`?
did you mean, why not updated the parent's state with the value and pass the state.value down back to the children ?

Comment: @Varinder im trying to understand how to set the value from inside a test, not purely with react.. its for testing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You correct doing `wrapper.find('input').instance().value = 'some text'` but you also need to trigger the change event on the input. You can do it like so:

```
const myInput = wrapper.find('input');
myInput.instance().value = 'some text';
myInput.simulate('change');
```

Or you can also directly trigger the change event with the value like this:

```
wrapper.find('input').simulate('change', { target: { value: 'some text' } });
```

This will only work for component, not function. There is no way of doing that because stateless components don't have methods. From the creator of the librairy:

> The answer is you don't test that function - you only test Component, and you add tests for all the code paths. You can't test that directly, and shouldn't.

If you want to test it, you have to convert it into a component.

Comment: Hey Vincent, I updated my post with my current component,
as you mantioned, I do save the ref into a variable.

How do I access *inputRef* from inside my test? 
I targeted my input like so: `component.find('input')`, now what ?

Comment: so no what would the expect command will look like ?

im still not sure,
`expect(input.prop('value')).toBe('new value')`? 
this doesnt work ofcourse.

in what way can you get the new value out of `input` ?

Comment: You cannot do that with stateless component, you need to convert it to a component (extends React.Component).

Comment: But how do people test stateless functions ?
it also part of the application that holds some buisness logic that need to be tested? 

isnt there any good common practice for this ?

Comment: The good practice is not to store business logic into your stateless component, only visual logic. If your component contains business logic, I really recommend you to move this logic elsewhere. Most people only test that a stateless component renders and that's it. It's a bad practice to test visual logic. Your stateless component is just a function returning a value, you test the returned value.